# How to display all records from a table with RedBeanPHP?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

What is the RedBeansPHP equivelant for this code?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["name"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

I've read that I need to use

```
$user = R::findAll('user');
```

but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$users = R::findAll('user');
foreach ($users as $user){
    echo $user->name.'<br>';
}
```

http://www.redbeanphp.com/finding findAll section. If you are using latest RedBean.